# VSeWSS CTP 1.3 March Custom Action Walkthrough

Tags: vsewss, development

Does anyone have a good walkthrough for creating a custom action using Visual Studio Extensions CTP 1.3 from March? I'm pretty sure it can be done, but I haven't seen a good explanation yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog entry addresses it exactly:

http://blogs.microlinkllc.com/tresing/archive/2009/10/20/create-a-sharepoint-custom-action-feature-with-vsewss.aspx